# Laravel MYSQL trigger

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, crud

I try to add the trigger to my CRUD app. I've created a migration for the trigger but it returns an error.
here it is my code for migration

```php
class CreateTrigger extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        DB::unprepared('
        CREATE TRIGGER getjenis AFTER INSERT ON `pesanan` FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                CALL getjenis();
            END
        ');
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('trigger');
    }
}
```

and here it is the error

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1109 Unknown table 'pesanan' in field list (SQL: insert into `pesanan` (`name`, `telpon`, `alamat`, `jenis`, `kecepatan`, `do`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Joko Mamat, 0813, Kasin, Cuci Basah, Kilat, Antar, 2019-11-23 02:16:28, 2019-11-23 02:16:28))

Please help.

Comment: the table is been created by a migration?

Comment: this error is about the seeds, not about the trigger... how are you running the migration command?

Comment: yap, just run php artisan migrate, is that take effect?

Comment: If the database is not filled with useful information, run php artisan migrate:fresh (will erase the database ) and let me know if any error occurs.. after that check if there is the table on the database and than seed the database